# Polymer: create paper-checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am creating a form for a survey which should ask for quesions out of a Json object.
My code works so far, but I feel like I miss knowledge of some polymer or JS functions that would make it more beautiful.
Screenshot:

[image]

Script:

```js
var questions = [
    {
        "question": "What do you want for christmas?"
        , "mode": "radio"
        , "answers": ["Nintendo", "iPony", "You", "A tiny little Shotgun"]
    }
];
console.log(questions);

function foo() {
    var question = document.createElement('div');
    question.className = 'question';
    question.innerHTML = "Frage:" + questions[0].question;
    console.log(question);
    var surveyQuestions =  document.getElementById("survey-questions");
    surveyQuestions.appendChild(question);

    var answers = document.createElement('div');
    answers.className = "answers";

    
    questions[0].answers.forEach(buildRadio);
    
    surveyQuestions.appendChild(answers);


    function buildRadio(item, index) {
        var paperCheckbox = document.createElement('paper-checkbox');
        var br = document.createElement('br');
        paperCheckbox.setAttribute("name",item);
        paperCheckbox.setAttribute("value",item);
        paperCheckbox.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].innerHTML = item;
        paperCheckbox.children[1].innerHTML = item;

        answers.appendChild(paperCheckbox);
        answers.appendChild(br);
    }
}
```

Another small exmaple for my problem:

```
<div class="card"></div>
```

creates

```
<div class="card style-scope survey-app"></div>
```

But

```
var card = document.createElement('div');
card.className = "card";
```

only creates

```
<div class="card"></div>
```

What would be best practice?

Comment: Have you tried using [`dom-repeat`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-repeat)?

Comment: What is your goal? After clicking on a radio button, you want to create a new card?

Comment: I did not try dom-repeat. I will check that, thanks! At this point I just want to create a form from a JSon Object. Later it will be an web-app for a human computer interaction study.

Comment: dom-repeat was a huge help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using `dom-repeat` and it works great:

```js
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{questions}}">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="question">Frage {{index}}: {{item.question}}</div>
                <template is="dom-if" if="{{_isCheckQuestion(item)}}">
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.answers}}">
                        <paper-checkbox>{{item}}</paper-checkbox>
                        <br>
                    </template>
                </template>
                <template is="dom-if" if="{{_isRadioQuestion(item)}}">
                    <paper-radio-group>
                        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.answers}}">
                            <paper-radio-button name="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-radio-button>
                            <br>
                        </template>
                    </paper-radio-group>
                </template>
            </div>
        </template>
```

But the `dom-if` is a little bit tricky

```js
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'survey-app'
        , properties: {
            prop1: {
                type: String
                , value: 'survey-app'
            }
        }
        , ready: function () {
            this.questions = [
                {
                    "question": "What do you want for christmas?"
                    , "mode": "check"
                    , "answers": ["Nintendo", "iPony", "You", "A tiny little Shotgun"]
        }


                , {
                    "question": "Yes or no?"
                    , "mode": "radio"
                    , "answers": ["yes", "no"]
        },

    ];
        }
        , _isCheckQuestion: function (question) {
            return question.mode == 'check'
        }
        , _isRadioQuestion: function (question) {
            return question.mode == 'radio'
        }
    });

</script>
```